# Increase "System Reserved" partition

Tags: partition, gparted

The goal is to expand a Windows 7 SSD `System Reserved Partition` from 39MB and add [500MB to the partition](https://superuser.com/a/1403146/45436).  I was able to reduce the size of the C:\ partition by 500 GB using Window's native diskmgmt.msc tool.   Attempts to use gParted and diskmgmt.msc to augment partition size were met with greyed-out controls.

I am able engage gParted via [sysrecuecd](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Installing-SystemRescueCd-on-a-USB-stick/)

## QUESTIONS

Why is gParted unable to increase the size of said partition?
What UNIX options are available to increase partition size?

## UPDATES

[image]

The empty partition was "moved between" the other two partitions:

[image]

Now that the unallocated partition is adjacent to the target partition, gParted is able to resize the target partition.  However, moving the large partition to the back with gParted creates a problem because the boot partition was not update to reflect the large partition move:

[image]

Q. What is the remedy to 'inform' the boot sector of the new location of the large main partition?

A. Bootrec.exe from the Windows 7 install disk as per [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues):

```
Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 media in the DVD drive, and then start the computer.
Press a key when you are prompted.
Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard, or an input method, and then click Next.
Click Repair your computer.
Select the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
Type Bootrec.exe, and then press Enter.
```

/dev/sda2's first sector is now 1110016 and last sector at 234441647

Comment: Please add screenshots of `Partition` -> `Information` (menu or right click) of the partition in GParted and also of `View` -> `File System Support` (where `ntfs` is listed).

Comment: You need to install the tools for gparted to use as Freddy said.

Comment: What's the status? `/dev/sda1` is now 500 MiB and the remaining unallocated space was used to enlarge `/dev/sda2` and that somehow corrupted Windows?
I fear this this is not a U&L question anymore. Boot from your Win USB stick and repair the partition via "Startup Repair" and if that doesn't help using the command prompt and [bootrec](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-code-0xc0000225-unable-to-find-the-file/06e7bb6c-d504-4a63-921c-2e3a383ec236).

Comment: Problem is solved: UNIX's gParted moved the empty partition so that the target partition could be expanded. Because the main partition was moved the boot partition had to be updated to reflect the change.